# R- grepl not matching characters when characters are present in R. (UTF- 8 encoding)

Tags: r, string, stringr, non-ascii-characters

I'm presently working with data which is UTF-8 encoded. I am trying to apply a `grepl` to see if certain strings are present in a body of text or not. But to no avail I was unable to get my desired result. (Note: I do know that the string is present).

To use an example, I have the following string of integers:

(**NOTE:** *Despite being numbers the structure of the data is a single character string*)

```r
>tancd[[1]]
[1] "1512 1463 1489 1460 1468 1497 32 1488 1457 1500 1460 1497 1506 1462 1494 1462 1512"
```

I want to see if the above is present in the string below (Which it is):

[Note: the desired string is framed with `***`- its not in the actual data]

```r
> dat
[1] "1488 32 1502 1461 1488 1461 1497 1502 1464 1514 1463 1497 32 1511 1493 1465 1512 1460 1497 1503 32 1488 1462 1514 32 1513 1473 1456 1502 1463 1506 32 1489 1468 1456 1506 1463 1512 1456 1489 1460 1497 1514 46 32 1502 1460 1513 1468 1473 1464 1506 1464 1492 32 1513 1473 1462 1492 1463 1499 1468 1465 1492 1458 1504 1460 1497 1501 32 1504 1460 1499 1456 1504 1464 1505 1460 1497 1501 32 1500 1462 1488 1457 1499 1465 1500 32 1489 1468 1460 1514 1456 1512 1493 1468 1502 1464 1514 1464 1503 44 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1505 1493 1465 1507 32 1492 1464 1488 1463 1513 1473 1456 1502 1493 1468 1512 1464 1492 32 1492 1464 1512 1460 1488 1513 1473 1493 1465 1504 1464 1492 44 32 1491 1468 1460 1489 1456 1512 1461 1497 32 ***1512 1463 1489 1468 1460 1497 32 1488 1457 1500 1460 1497 1506 1462 1494 1462 1512*** 46 32 1493 1463 1495 1458 1499 1464 1502 1460 1497 1501 32 1488 1493 1465 1502 1456 1512 1460 1497 1501 44 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1495 1458 1510 1493 1465 1514 46 32 1512 1463 1489 1468 1464 1503 32 1490 1468 1463 1502 1456 1500 1460 1497 1488 1461 1500 32 1488 1493 1465 1502 1461 1512 44 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1513 1473 1462 1497 1468 1463 1506 1458 1500 1462 1492 32 1506 1463 1502 1468 1493 1468 1491 32 1492 1463 1513 1468 1473 1464 1495 1463 1512 46 32 1502 1463 1506 1458 1513 1474 1462 1492 32 1513 1473 1462 1489 1468 1464 1488 1493 1468 32 1489 1464 1504 1464 1497 1493 32 1502 1460 1489 1468 1461 1497 1514 32 1492 1463 1502 1468 1460 1513 1473 1456 1514 1468 1462 1492 44 32 1488 1464 1502 1456 1512 1493 1468 32 1500 1493 1465 44 32 1500 1465 1488 32 1511 1464 1512 1460 1497 1504 1493 1468 32 1488 1462 1514 32 1513 1473 1456 1502 1463 1506 46 32 1488 1464 1502 1463 1512 32 1500 1464 1492 1462 1501 44 32 1488 1460 1501 32 1500 1465 1488 32 1506 1464 1500 1464 1492 32 1506 1463 1502 1468 1493 1468 1491 32 1492 1463 1513 1468 1473 1463 1495 1463 1512 44 32 1495 1463 1497 1468 1464 1489 1460 1497 1503 32 1488 1463 1514 1468 1462 1501 32 1500 1460 1511 1456 1512 1493 1465 1514 46 32 1493 1456 1500 1465 1488 32 1494 1493 1465 32 1489 1468 1460 1500 1456 1489 1463 1491 44 32 1488 1462 1500 1468 1464 1488 32 1499 1468 1464 1500 32 1502 1463 1492 32 1513 1468 1473 1462 1488 1464 1502 1456 1512 1493 1468 32 1495 1458 1499 1464 1502 1460 1497 1501 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1495 1458 1510 1493 1465 1514 44 32 1502 1460 1510 1456 1493 1464 1514 1464 1503 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1513 1473 1462 1497 1468 1463 1506 1458 1500 1462 1492 32 1506 1463 1502 1468 1493 1468 1491 32 1492 1463 1513 1468 1473 1464 1495 1463 1512 46 32 1492 1462 1511 1456 1496 1461 1512 32 1495 1458 1500 1464 1489 1460 1497 1501 32 1493 1456 1488 1461 1489 1464 1512 1460 1497 1501 44 32 1502 1460 1510 1456 1493 1464 1514 1464 1503 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1513 1473 1462 1497 1468 1463 1506 1458 1500 1462 1492 32 1506 1463 1502 1468 1493 1468 1491 32 1492 1463 1513 1468 1473 1464 1495 1463 1512 46 32 1493 1456 1499 1464 1500 32 1492 1463 1504 1468 1462 1488 1457 1499 1464 1500 1460 1497 1501 32 1500 1456 1497 1493 1465 1501 32 1488 1462 1495 1464 1491 44 32 1502 1460 1510 1456 1493 1464 1514 1464 1503 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1513 1473 1462 1497 1468 1463 1506 1458 1500 1462 1492 32 1506 1463 1502 1468 1493 1468 1491 32 1492 1463 1513 1468 1473 1464 1495 1463 1512 46 32 1488 1460 1501 32 1499 1468 1461 1503 44 32 1500 1464 1502 1468 1464 1492 32 1488 1464 1502 1456 1512 1493 1468 32 1495 1458 1499 1464 1502 1460 1497 1501 32 1506 1463 1491 32 1495 1458 1510 1493 1465 1514 44 32 1499 1468 1456 1491 1461 1497 32 1500 1456 1492 1463 1512 1456 1495 1460 1497 1511 32 1488 1462 1514 32 1492 1464 1488 1464 1491 1464 1501 32 1502 1460 1503 32 1492 1464 1506 1458 1489 1461 1512 1464 1492 58"
```

## My Problem:

When I use the `grepl` I get the following result:

```r
> grepl(tancd[[1]],dat)
[1] FALSE
```

Similarly if I use `string_detect()` from the `stringr` package I get the same result:

```r
> str_detect(tancd[[1]],dat)
[1] FALSE
```

Is there a way to grepl this set and get the <del>correct</del> desired result?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I am not able to find the tancd[[1]] pattern in dat, I have used ctrl+F to do so. Not sure why you are expecting a TRUE. The position of 1468 and 1460 is different after the string "1512 1463 1489..."  Thanks. `Also use fixed = TRUE, when you want to ignore regex in grep`

Answer (score 1):

The string you have between the astrisks is different than the string you are looking for.

```
string in dat    :  "1512 1463 1489 1468 1460 1497 32 1488 1457 1500 1460 1497 1506 1462 1494 1462 1512"
string in tancd  :  "1512 1463 1489 1460 1468 1497 32 1488 1457 1500 1460 1497 1506 1462 1494 1462 1512"
```

You'll notice that 1468 and 1460 are inverted in tancd. If you fix tancd it should work.

```
tancd[[1]] <- "1512 1463 1489 1468 1460 1497 32 1488 1457 1500 1460 1497 1506 1462 1494 1462 1512"

grepl(dat, pattern=tancd[[1]])
```